# React not defined when installed with webpack

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, jasmine

I am trying to install React using webpack. It's part of a Rails project. I'm following [this tutorial](http://clarkdave.net/2015/01/how-to-use-webpack-with-rails/)

The tutorial recommends removing everything from app/assets/javascripts (which I have not done yet - I still have jquery, jquery_ujs, and d3 in there) putting my javascript into a separate directory and making that my 'source', and then making app/assets/javascripts the 'destination' directory in my webpack configuration. I have named my source directory app/frontend/javascripts, in keeping with the tutorial.

Here's what my webpack.config.js file looks like:

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = [{
  name: 'chartComponent',
  entry: './app/frontend/javascripts/entry.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'assets', 'javascripts'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: [/\.jsx$/],
        loaders: ["jsx-loader?insertPragma=React.DOM&harmony"],
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.js', '.jsx']
  }
}];
```

I confess I don't know what all these settings do, particularly the 'loaders' settings, but it's my understanding that 'entry' should point to the entry point for my webpack-ed javascript, and 'output' should specify the directory and filename for the compiled javascript.

I have specified the file 'app/frontend/javascripts/entry.js' as my entry point. The file looks like this:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Chart = require('react-d3-core').Chart;
var LineChart = require('react-d3-basic').LineChart;
```

Webpack runs ok, and generates the file 'app/assets/javascripts/bundle.js', as expected. However, when I include the bundle file either in my Rails app, or in my Jasmine test, the global vars React, ReactDOM, etc, are not available. At the console, attempting to access React, I get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined

I can successfully access the global variables `d3` and `$` set up by d3.js and jquery.js respectively, but I am not managing those through webpack.

I think I must be wrong in expecting the variables set up in my webpack entry file to be available. Moreover, it seems like such a variable should be set up within the included file, not declared by me - just like `d3` and `$` are set up without my declaring them and setting their value. But, when I look at bundle.js, I do see `var React = ....`. (In more than one place, which I don't get, but whatever). So I would think the variable would at least be defined.

In short, how do I access React (or any other library I've included with webpack) from my app and tests? Any help appreciated!

Comment: My guess is that react isn't installed. Did you enter `npm install --save react` at some point? (Or is `react` present in your package.json dependencies?)

Comment: you need to do `import React from 'react'` in your jsx files even if you are not explicitly calling `React`. the jsx will get compiled down into react's api.

Comment: @Daniel I did install react - when I run `npm view react version`, I get 15.4.2. This is also the version number in my package.json file under "dependencies"

Comment: no...post your jsx files. you need to do `const React = require('react')` even though your jsx code does not explicitly call react anywhere. jsx will get compiled down to react api which *does* call react. its not an issue of whether you installed it or not.

Comment: @DanielLizik I haven't even written any jsx yet - I created a file called 'entry.js' which I've configured webpack to use as the entry point. In that file, I'm creating `var React = require('react')`. When I look at the bundle created by webpack, those declarations are there, but they appear to be inside an anonymous function, so I don't think I can expect them to be in the global namespace.

Comment: why do they have to be global? webpack doesnt do that by default, you need to use `webpack.ProvidePlugin` to expose globals.

Comment: The vars I created in entry.js don't have to be global - but if this was working, wouldn't there be a global variable called `React`, where I could call things like `React.createElement` etc?

Comment: Ok I think I know my problem - I need to import the React module, then I can access React. Thanks @DanielLizik, I get it now :) My problem now becomes figuring out how to use the import syntax with my Jasmine spec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any variable defined inside ES2015 module is available only in this module. The same applies to imported modules - importing module doesn't make this module to be available in global scope. If you really need to make some module variable to be available globally you have to assign it to `window` property:

```
var React = require('react');
window.React = React;
```

Comment: I don't necessarily need a global variable; I think my problem is that I don't fully understand what webpack is doing. I'm including the bundle file that gets generated by webpack, it looks like it's got React in it, but I don't know how to access React in my app or test

Comment: Yes, `React` library is included in bundle outputed by webpack but webpack 'encapsulates' modules so their code is not available globally. `react` lib is included in generated bundle but as internal module - not as global one. Please read how Webpack works before using it. Besides, it's not a webpack specific issue but generally code of ES2015 modules is not available outside files in which they're imported

Comment: Thanks for the insight - I see I have to import React to use it. now I need to figure out how to use the import syntax in my Jasmine spec, but that's a different question.